# json_search and json_remove in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, json-remove, json-search

```
notice
[
 {
   "date": "2022. 10. 16.", 
   "type": 3, 
   "title": "friend", 
   "content": "JJ friend", 
   "parameter": "test"
 }, 
 {
   "date": "2022. 10. 16.", 
   "type": 3, 
   "title": "friend", 
   "content": "testtest friend", 
   "parameter": "test1"
  }
]
```

I wanna search and remove in json {"date": "2022. 10. 16.","type": 3,"title": "friend","content": "testtest friend","parameter": "test1"} where id = 'test2'

There's a separate column for the ID.

```
update UserTable set notice = json_remove(notice, json_search(notice, 'one', 
'{"date": "2022. 10. 16.","type": 3,"title": "friend","content": "testtest friend","parameter": "test1"}')) where id = 'test2'";
```

Comment: How do you uniquely identify the json object you want to remove from the array you have?

Comment: I don't have a unique ID that I can identify, but I want it to be deleted if the contents of json are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(jsonvalue)
FROM src_table
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(src_table.notice,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (jsonvalue JSON PATH '$')) jsontable
WHERE jsonvalue <> CAST('{"date": "2022. 10. 16.","type": 3,"title": "friend","content": "testtest friend","parameter": "test1"}' AS JSON)
```

Comment: I have a separate column of ID, can I apply that too?

Comment: @JiNyeok_S I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: Can i make json_table by taking Row's notice with ID column of 'test2'?

Comment: @JiNyeok_S `test2` is a table which is not mentioned in your original post? if so then this is separate question, and you'd create another topic.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thank you for your help.